# How can I find a specific process with "top" in a Mac terminal

Tags: macos, grep

I've tried `top | grep skype` for example but it doesn't work. I'm trying to find a specific process by name.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use this instead: `ps -ax | grep -i skype`

Comment: The problem with ps is that it only displays processes that have a terminal attached. It doesn't work.

Comment: With the -x flag, ps should show all processes. Are you certain skype is running? Try `ps -ax | grep -i skype`

Answer (score 13):

On Linux, the `top` command supports the `-p` option to monitor specific PIDs. On MacOS, the `-p` option is called `-pid` instead.

```
# Get the PID of the process
pgrep Skype

# Then
top -pid <put PID here>

# Or more succinctly:
top -pid `pgrep Skype`
```

If you do this a lot, you could turn this into a function and add it to  `~/.bash_profile`:

```
# Add this to ~/.bash_profile
function topgrep() {
    if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then 
        echo "Usage: topgrep <expression>"
    else 
        top -pid `pgrep $1`
    fi
}
```

Now you can simply use `topgrep Skype` instead, which will run like usual but it will only show the process(es) matching `expression`.

Comment: on OSX i think it's `top -pid`

Comment: I think this was the best answer using `top -pid`.  Added some improvements in edit.

Comment: What if there are multiple processes running with the same name but different PIDs? How do you see them all

Answer (score 12):

Use: `top -l 0 | grep Skype`

The 0 is for infinite samples.  You can also limit the number of samples to a positive number.

Comment: Just checked and the name of the process in top is `Skype` not `skype`.  Updated the answer.

Comment: Using the `grep -i` option would fix the problem

Answer (score 7):

if you really love top, you could try:

```
top -b -n 1 | grep skype
```

e.g.

```
kent$  top -b -n 1 |grep dropbox
 4039 kent      20   0  184m  14m 5464 S    0  0.4   0:58.30 dropbox
```

Comment: invalid option or syntax: -bn1

Comment: well it worked here. I updated the answer, try it again please.

Comment: @Kent Worked for me. `Linux archvbox 4.1.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Aug 11 15:41:14 CEST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux` Cool to have alternate ways of doing things! (`ps` and `top`)

Comment: Updated to include variants for both OS X (OP) and Linux. Strictly speaking, with the update, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Also, the single sample isn't a must. On the contrary, I typically use `grep` to filter output flowing out of `top`.

Answer (score 2):

use [ps](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA21964?viewlocale=en_US) instead of top.

Comment: The problem with ps is that it only displays processes that have a terminal attached. It doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried with '-a' or '-A' or 'aux'  options? I'm a linux user and in my os ps works fine.

Comment: yes, for linux it works fine. mac is another story unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2):

Tested on MacOSX Mojave. It works a bit different than linux.

`top -pid` doesn't expect a comma separated list of pids, it expects only one pid. So I had to changed it a little to work with several pids.

```
top -pid $(pgrep -d ' -pid ' -f Python)
```

filter all Python process on top. It essentially becomes something like this:

```
top -pid 123 -pid 836 -pid 654
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. I'm even looking to monitor python processes specifically. Straight copy/paste and worked.

Comment: Oh yeah! Finally the top command I was looking for <3

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use `pgrep skype` to find the process.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `ps -ax | less`

From within `less`, you can type in <kbd>/</kbd>`skype`<kbd>Enter</kbd> to search for processes with names containing "skype".

Answer (score 0):

I prefer ps -aux over ps -ax, as -aux provides additional info related to the userid starting the process, start time, memory usage (%mem, vsz, rss). (Yes, detached processed without tty is also displayed).

The command htop is also a good alternative to top. Htop provides ways to interactively search, filter and sort the processes.